# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer not loading pdf if opens that component after some time of page refresh

Tags: angular, pdf, pdf-viewer, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

For pdf viewer in angular, I am using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer: 10.0.0-alpha.8
I am using that pdf in one of the components (PDFViewerComponent), If I open that component after project start/page refresh it works perfectly. But when I open another component and after 1/2 mins navigate to PDFViewerComponent then it shows like this:
[image]

And there are no errors on the console regarding this.
Thanks..

Comment: How does it show normally?

Comment: Normally it works like the example shown on this link: https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/simple.

Comment: Have you checked the data passing to the pdf component when you go back?

Comment: Data passing is correct because other things on the component are working properly like data is getting filled in inputs except for pdf. (data is fetched from BE from ngOnInit() )

Comment: If you're able to send me a reproducer, please open a bug ticket at https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues.

Comment: got exactly the same issue but when using book mode. it doesn't render the right hand side page . if I do a full page refresh it works fine. (apart from the initial load)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and I solved it by adding an *ngif to the viewer to view it only if the pdf was loaded.

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer *ngIf="provisionService.displayPdfDialog"
                             [src]="provisionService.pdfFile"
                             [useBrowserLocale]="true"
                             [minifiedJSLibraries]="false">
</ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```